# Inkscape LaTeX option missing

Tags: inkscape, latex

I just recently started using inkscape and I want to insert a latex formula.

Doing some web searches I got to know it must appear under Extensions>Render>LaTeX.

But when I tried to follow that the LaTeX option is not present under that menu.

[image]

Where would I find the option to include latex equations and do I need to install something else ?

I have latex installed on my machine. I'll attach some version information below.

```
zain@ubuntu:~$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.5
Copyright 2023 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.40; using libpng 1.6.40
Compiled with zlib 1.2.13; using zlib 1.2.13
Compiled with xpdf version 4.04
```

Comment: To use LaTeX, you have to install an extension. It doesn't come with Inkscape.  I've never had success installing it however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I was using the snap package.

To fix this issue, I removed the snap package and installed it from apt instead.

`sudo snap remove inkscape`

Followed by

`sudo apt install inkscape`